# Calculate my product stock. (SQL)

Tags: sql

So I have a product for example cake (It's a soft for a cofeteria). I know that my cake expires after 48h.
Today, for example I have 10 cakes in my stock, and I want to know  if some of my cakes are expired, to send it back to deposit, and eliminate it from my stock.

I have my product table which contains product and expiration date in hours (Example: 48 h)

I have another table where I calculate my stock now. (And a procedure who does that).

Comment: (1) I removed the incompatible database tags.  (2) Provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Do you have Manu. time in stock table?

Comment: What have you done so far and what problems have your faced ?. Looks like a pretty easy join with your current stock table, and filtering with product expiration date over the system datetime.

Comment: In stock table I have only my stock.(I don't have a date).
I was thinking to add another table and insert the date when I receive the cake and the quantity. Then calculate somehow how many I sold in some days...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might required to add new columns in `Production` tracking table and `Sale` table, that might be either `BatchNumber` or `ProductionDate`, then get list of cake produced and its batch number subtract with list of cake sold for each BatchNumber based on production time display it as expired or tasty.

```
SELECT
    Product.ProductName,
    Production.BatchNumber,
    SUM(Production.Qty) - SUM(Sale.Qty) AS Stock
    CASE WHEN DATEADD(hh, Product.ExpireInHrs, Production.ProductionTime) >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP THEN 'Expired' ELSE 'Tasty' END
FROM Product
    INNER JOIN Production ON Production.ProductId = Product.ProductId
    INNER JOIN Sale ON Sale.ProductId = Product.ProductId AND Production.BatchNumber = Sale.BatchNumber
GROUP BY
    Product.ProductName,
    Production.BatchNumber
```

For the query above I presume that you have three tables `Product`, `Production` and `Sale` with `BatchNumber` columns in `Production` and `Sale` table, `ProductionTime` column in `Production` table.